# Create an xml file named after the current project using NuGet and PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, project, nuget

I'm trying to use NuGet to place an xml file into the project, and I'd like the XML file to be named after the project, i.e. `ConsoleApplication1.xml`. Unless I'm missing something, I don't think it's possible without using PowerShell to perform a rename/create the file manually via the script.

And so, is there a way to trivially do it, without writing custom PowerShell to do it?

Comment: Why would you use NuGet.exe to create an XML file? Nuget handles dependency management. Are you looking at renaming the `packages\repositories.config` config that nuget generates?

Comment: No, as a dependency to my project I also need a custom XML file, that is named after the project. I can already deploy an arbitrary file using `target="content"`, but I was hoping to control the output name too.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an msbuild postbuild event to rename the file. Sometimes the simplest solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the xml tasks in the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) would be better suited for this task.